# Progress Bar using jQuery with a Grails backend?

Tags: java, jquery, grails, groovy

I've written an excel upload function that allows a user to upload an excel sheet through a web interface and it will commit it to a table. The problem is that with a table with many records, it takes some time to go through each record and check for changes, so it tends to hang. What would be the best solution for a progress bar type control that I could use to show the users that it is indeed processing the workbook?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe a simple "I'm working" message would do, maybe even with [an animated wait spinner](http://www.ajaxload.info/).

Comment: Ended up going with this option... easiest to code and still provides the user with an indication that something is happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do it that way, the Grails jQuery [plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/jquery) works like it should, and jQuery does include a progress bar which is easy to update as long as you know how far along you are. Far easier though would be to use Bobby's recommendation of a wait gif.

Answer (score 0):

If the process takes a long time, you may consider an asynchronous approach where you allow the user to upload one or more files and then provide them with a widget that shows them the status of all of their file uploads. This increases the responsiveness of the application and provides for a better user experience.

See how GMail does file attachments, or how Flickr does image uploads through the site for some examples.